# A planar 2-connected graph. G-e1-e2 is not connected. Do e1 and e2 belong to the same face?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

**Problem:**

$G$ is a planar 2-connected graph. $G-e_1-e_2$ is not connected.

Is it true, that $e_1$ and $e_2$ belong to the same face?

**Solution**:

I thought about the fact:

> $G$ is a planar 2-connected graph $\iff$ its every face is a simple cycle (1).

So, let $e_1$ and $e_2$ belong to the different faces. Using the fact (1) we can say that $e_1$ and $e_2$ belong to the different simple cycles, but if we delete 2 edges from two different simple cycles of 2-connected graph, it will be connected $=>?!$ Сontradiction, $e_1$ and $e_2$ belong to the different faces.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: Seems like this is true. What do you think? What did you try?

Comment: I thought about the fact that a graph is a planar 2-connected graph <=> its every face is a simple cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof doesn't work because both the statements "$e_1$ and $e_2$ belong to different faces"  and "$e_1$ and $e_2$ belong to different simple cycles" are imprecise, and once you make them precise, the second no longer follows from the first.

We are assuming for contradiction that it is *not* true that $e_1$ and $e_2$ belong to the same face. Well, actually, $e_1$ and $e_2$ might each belong to up to two faces. So the negation that we're assuming for contradiction should read "there is no face $F$ which contains both $e_1$ and $e_2$".

All faces are simple cycles, but not all simple cycles are faces. So we *cannot* conclude the broader statement "there is no simple cycle $C$ which contains both $e_1$ and $e_2$". There might be some cycles like this: they're just not faces.

The statement "If $G$ is a $2$-connected graph and $e_1$ and $e_2$ are edges such that no simple cycle $C$ contains both $e_1$ and $e_2$, then $G-e_1-e_2$ is connected" is true, though it requires proof. Even so, it does not solve this problem, because we're not given enough information to prove the hypothesis of this statement.

---

To prove this result, suppose that $G-e_1-e_2$ is disconnected. Then, in a plane embedding of $G$, we can draw a closed curve around one of the two components of $G-e_1-e_2$ which doesn't touch any vertices or edges of $G$.

Both $e_1$ and $e_2$ must go from that component to the other component of $G-e_1-e_2$, so they must both cross that curve. This means that some segment of that curve is a path which goes from the interior of $e_1$ to the interior of $e_2$, without touching any other edges or any vertices. This is only possible if $e_1$ and $e_2$ are part of the same face.